# the colloquial meaning of 嫌なところ見られた

Tags: translation, colloquial-language

In a story, a hated character comes into the room. The narrator says 嫌{いや｝なところ見｛み｝られた The literal translation doesn't make much sense, as I can't see what "bad place" she's talking about. I tried to research it, and it seems to be some sort of colloquialism. My best guess is that it could translate to "I just stepped into hell," or "this is like hell." Of course, I would like to be certain. Thank you.

Comment: Context please... What story?

Answer (score 5):

ところ has [many abstract meanings](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%93%E3%82%8D). This ところ is not a physical place but a "situation" or "scene", or more concretely, what the narrator was just doing. It's not a colloquialism. See: [A bunch of questions about ところ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27541/5010)

This 嫌な ("bad") just refers to the fact that the narrator did not want the other character to see what he was doing. The whole sentence roughly means "I was seen at a bad time."