# 「認めるところである」とはどういう意味ですか。

Tags: meaning

下の例文で「ところであり」ってどういう意味ですか。

> 例文）「そのすぐれた才能はだれもが認める**ところであり**、巧自身、大人が相手であっても自分の球が打たれるなどとは考えていません。」

Answer (score 6, accepted):

明鏡国語辞典's definition is as follows:

> #### ところ
>
> ❽《連体修飾句を受けて》
>   ㋐その語句の表す事柄の内容の意。「それこそ私の望むところだ」「聞くところによるとこうだ」「余すところなく打ち明ける」
>   ▶漢文で用言を体言化する助辞「所」を訓読したところから。

その語句の表す事柄の内容 means "the thing/fact that it (=the preceding relative clause) represents". This is fairly vague :D

Essentially, this ところ is very similar to こと/もの except that ところ is used only in a few (often literary) fixed expressions. This ところ means "thing to <verb>" or "what to <verb>".

- 望むところだ
  That is exactly what I want! / Bring it on!
- 聞くところによると…
  From what I heard...
- 余すところなく ≒ 余すことなく
  exhaustively; every last one of ～ (literally "without things to leave")
- 思うところがある
  to have one's reasons; to have a (certain) idea

So this 認めるところである is roughly the same as 認めることである. The first half of the sentence means "(His) excellent talent is something everyone acknowledges".

See Also:

- [What does 望むところだ mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56742/5010)