# What does「とこ」mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> 学校なんて つまらないとこ
> すぐやめられると思ってたけど

> もう少し このままで

> 未練ができちゃったから

I came across these sentences while watching The Quintessential Quintuplets (season 2, episode 1, 5 mins in).

My understanding of the context is that the character speaking was thinking of quitting school, but couldn't decide whether or not to.

If I were to try and translate this:

> "I thought that school was boring"

> "but I'm going to stay for a little longer"

> "Because made an attachment that I can't leave behind"

What does 「とこ」 mean in the first part? I thought it was a shortened form of ところ but the rules I found for that were only with verbs. Is there a difference when used with adjectives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial guess is correct. This とこ is a colloquial variation of ところ, and it just means "place" here. It can be safely modified by an adjective; つまらないとこ is "a boring place".

> 学校なんて つまらないとこ すぐやめられると思ってたけど
> I was thinking I could quit a boring place like school right away, but...

とこ(ろ) has several derivative usages (like [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27541/5010) and [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23738/5010)), and you seem to have run into some article that describes such derivative usages of the word. But とこ(ろ) in your question is a simple noun that just means "place".